# Why System hangs while saving in libre office for some time?

Tags: libreoffice

Why System hangs while saving in libre office for some time?

When I save data in Libre office calc the screen darkens for sometime and takes about 10 secs to run again. Every time I save, it happens and its irritating. Please help me.

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked in other forums.  It seems that there are a variety of causes and solutions.  Some things I would suggest:

- Be sure to save in .ods format, not .xls or .xlsx
- Try [resetting your LibreOffice profile](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?p=58403#p58403).
- Apache OpenOffice may be faster than LibreOffice on some systems.

Some things to keep in mind:

- Large documents with complex formatting will take longer to save.
- Even small documents will take a few seconds to save because the file must be zipped up first.  Notice how small the file size is, which is a result of zipping.

Check out these links:

- http://en.libreofficeforum.org/node/502
- https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/32972/why-the-super-slow-saves-in-calc/
- https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/154/why-is-calc-so-much-slower-at-openingsaving-files-than-ms-office-win7-x64/
- https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=63170